# Why is my subselect no working?

Tags: db2, subquery

I have this query and I want to get all records that have both ER and (OM, MT, or NM) money types, but this query brings back everything with just ER and disergards my subselect. The records key is SSN, PLAN, MONEY_TYPE_CD so I want all the SSNs that have ER and (OM, MT, or NM).  Hope this is clearer.  Any help is appreciated.

```
SELECT A.SSN, A.MONEY_TYPE_CD, A.PLAN_TYPE, A.ER_NUM
FROM FUND_DTL A                                                    
WHERE A.MONEY_TYPE_CD = 'ER'                             
  AND A.SSN IN (
      SELECT SSN                                
      FROM FUND_DTL                             
      WHERE MONEY_TYPE_CD IN ('OM', 'MT', 'NM')
  )              
WITH UR;
```

Comment: How can one record have both 'ER' and not-'ER' value in `MONEY_TYPE`? You may want to re-state your question.

Comment: @mustaccio,  MONEY_CD is part of the key according to the question..

Answer (score 0):

The `WHERE A.MONEY_TYPE_CD = 'ER'` is restricting the results set to just the 'ER' codes.

You want something more like so...

```
SELECT A.SSN, A.MONEY_TYPE_CD, A.PLAN_TYPE, A.ER_NUM 
FROM FUND_DTL A
WHERE A.SSN IN (SELECT SSN
                FROM FUND_DTL
                WHERE MONEY_TYPE_CD IN ('OM', 'MT', 'NM'))
  AND A.SSN IN (SELECT SSN
                FROM FUND_DTL
                WHERE MONEY_TYPE_CD = 'ER')
WITH UR;
```

Another version using INTERSECT

```
SELECT A.SSN, A.MONEY_TYPE_CD, A.PLAN_TYPE, A.ER_NUM 
FROM FUND_DTL A
WHERE A.SSN IN (SELECT SSN
                FROM FUND_DTL
                WHERE MONEY_TYPE_CD IN ('OM', 'MT', 'NM')
                INTERSECT  
                SELECT SSN
                FROM FUND_DTL
                WHERE MONEY_TYPE_CD = 'ER')
WITH UR;
```

Both  say give me any record whose SSN appears in both the set of SSNs with 'ER' and the set of SSNs with ('OM', 'MT', 'NM')

Comment: thanks!  now my question is how do I add another column into the subselect like the plan type?  that was actually my problem to begin with.  thx!

Comment: `WHERE (colA, colB) IN (SELECT colA, colB FROM ...`)

Comment: Thanks.  I finally found something online.  :)